# BindingRedirect with changes to Assembly Names

Tags: telerik, activereports, assembly-binding-redirect

I'm trying to convert some Active Report 6 reports to Telerik Reporting.  Teleriks' build in conversion tool, however, was built to work with Active Report 3.

I found this KB article of Telerik's: http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/reporting/details/converting-reports-from-activereports, which talks about how to use updated versions of AR3 other than the one they are built against...  But because there was a DLL name change (ActiveReports3 was changed to ActiveReports6), it's not working.

Is there a way to say 'If you see a DLL request for AR3, send it to this new assembly named AR6'?  I don't believe I can use something like AppDomain.AssemblyResolve event because I don't have access to the code of the converter tool or the message boxes it brings up.

I know that **if** this is possible, it will likely blow up my reports and I'd have to build them new anyway, but my reports are super simple (lines, text boxes, shapes), so hopefully (maybe) if I can get this to work, it won't be AS hard.  No way to know until I try!

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amanda, since I work for GrapeCity, I have to ask.  Is there any reason why you are moving away from ActiveReports to Telerik?  technical reasons? business changes?  either way, would love to know what happened.

On converting to telerik, what format are the reports in?  rpx or code behind?  It is lot easier if they are rpx files.  what you can do is install ActiveReports for .net 3.0; Create a project that has arn3; (add one arn3 template to the project, that will add all the references and such); then add all the rpx files from the project that uses ar6.  I believe telerik conversion tool will then pick it up for conversion.

If they are cs/vb files; I am not sure if telerik handles them too or not.  If they dont, then they can be converted to rpx format ( you will have to manually the code behind event implementation to the script and go from there.

Let me know if you need any help.

Comment: Rajnish,

Thank you for your tips!  I was able to installed AR3 version 5.3.1436.2 and take the layout from AR6 to a new solution in AR3 with no obvious issues.  Thanks for that thought!  Past this point, I believe this is a Telerik issue.  Or it could be a user issue - it is a Monday morning!  XD

As for why we're moving away, that's a decision that was above my paygrade so I can't offer an exact reasoning.  Big bosses tell me to convert, so I convert.

Thank you again!  <3

Edit: Foiled again by Enter!

Comment: Ha, it WAS a user issue!  What I was expecting, and what the converter was looking for were two different things.  I have now corrected the issue.  Thank you!